# Code Composer 4 (Eclipse based)- makefiles

Tags: eclipse, makefile, signal-processing, rtos, texas-instruments

How do I prevent Code Composer 4 (which is based on Eclipse) from generating its own makefile and use the one I provide instead?

Background:
I am starting a FreeRTOS project on a MSP430F5436 using Code Composer 4 and have a demo app with a supplied make file)

Thanks!

Comment: In my experience you pay TI enough for Code Composer to expect them to provide support rather than asking here!

Comment: I was using the free version for programs under 16Kb.

Answer (score 0):

In the **project property** for CCS 4.0, you have an option about the makefile saying 'use custom makefile'. I knbow there is a lot of options there !

I don't have CCS 4.0 in front of me right now, but I will have a look to the right menu Tuesday.

Of course, you starting project must not use a DSP/BIOS template.